# ITV zone shapefile

Tags: shapefile, data, united-kingdom

Where can we get ITV zone shapefiles for the UK? I need to create filled maps using this data.

Comment: ITV the tv channel? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITV_%28TV_channel%29

Comment: I guess if you get really stuck, you could digitize this: http://www.itvmedia.co.uk/new-to-itv/itv-regions

Comment: The problem is the regions transmission coverage overlaps http://www.ukfree.tv/maps/itv/8